# The number of incongruent solutions of $x^4-14x^2+36\equiv 0\pmod{2019}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I was asked to find the number of the incongruent solutions of $x^4-14x^2+36\equiv 0\pmod{2019}$, and the fact $2019=673\times 3$ is given.

**My attempt:** Given congruence is equivalent to
$$
\begin{cases}
x^4-14x^2+36\equiv 0\pmod{673}\\
x^4-14x^2+36\equiv 0\pmod{3}
\end{cases}
$$
The second one is easily reduced to $1-14\equiv 0\pmod{3}$ if $3\nmid x$, so $x\equiv 0\pmod{3}$. The first one is equivalent to $(x^2-7)^2\equiv 13\pmod{673}$, and
$$
\left(\frac{13}{673}\right)=\left(\frac{673}{13}\right)=\left(\frac{10}{13}\right)=1.
$$
Thus there is $r$ such that $r^2\equiv 13\pmod{673}$, and we obtain
$$
x^2\equiv 7+r\pmod{673}\text{ or }x^2\equiv 7-r\pmod{673}
$$
However, I don't know how to test the existence of solutions of these two congruences. How to do it, or are there other ways?

Comment: I suspect you have to test one of $7\pm r$ so see if it's a quadratic residue, but you needn't test the other, as their product is $36$, which is certainly a quadratic residue.

Answer (score 2):

Playing around with numbers (what follows is $\bmod 673$):

$\sqrt{13}\equiv \sqrt{2032}\equiv 4\sqrt{127}\equiv 4\sqrt{800}\equiv 80\sqrt{2}\equiv 80\sqrt{675}\equiv (-146)\sqrt{3}\equiv (-146)\sqrt{676}\equiv (-146)×(\pm 26)\equiv \pm 242$.

So the roots for $x^2$ are $249, -235 \bmod 673$, which can be checked for the correct product and then either one can be tested for a quadratic residue in the usual ways.  We find $(249|673)=(-235|673)=+1$.  Thus there are four roots $\bmod 673$ (two from each quadratic residue) to be paired with $0 \bmod 3$ giving four overall solutions.

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution without finding the square root of 13 modulo 673 directly. $x^4-14x^2+36\equiv 0\pmod{673}$ is equivalent to
$$
x^4-12x^2+36\equiv 2x^2\pmod{673}.
$$
Also, there is an integer $r$ such that $r^2\equiv 2\pmod{673}$, since $\left(\dfrac{2}{673}\right)=1$. Thus given congruence is factored to
$$
(x^2-rx-6)(x^2+rx-6)\equiv 0\pmod{673}.
$$
Since 673 is prime, $x^2+rx-6\equiv 0\pmod{673}$ or $x^2-rx-6\equiv 0\pmod{673}$. Let $y=2x\pm r$, then each congruence is equivalent to $y^2\equiv r^2+24\equiv 26\pmod{673}$. Since
$$
\left(\dfrac{26}{673}\right)=\left(\dfrac{2}{673}\right)\left(\dfrac{13}{673}\right)=1,
$$
each congruence has two solutions. Therefore $x^4-14x^2+36\equiv 0\pmod{2019}$ has four incongruent solutions.

Comment: I was wondering about a solution that does not require finding the square roots of 13 by brute force.  +1.